# EE's Compatibility Wizard - what modules are in suggested & optional?

Tags: compatibility

Trying to work out what server modules (*nix) I need the hosting admin to install to have green across the board.

Specifically we currently have No for the following:

- CAPTCHAs feature and watermarking in Image Gallery
- JPEG Image Resising User GD (or GD 2)

See result of running the wizard below.

[image: Compatibility Wizard Result]

Thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I checked and managed to work out with the hosting provider what needed to be done. Basically with the PHP config, we needed the following flags set:

For CAPTCHA support:

```
'--enable-gd-native-ttf'
```

For JPEG Image Resizing support (path different depending on server setup):

```
'--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you install Expression Engine and you doesn't need a Captcha feature (to avoid spams), or no need to resize jpeg picture, it will works fine.

But if you really need a system similar to avoid spams, exists a lot of addons about this.

Comment: Sorry Stéphane, this didn't really assist my question.

Comment: no problems. Your question was not very clear.